# How can I stop an object (file) from being accessed over http(s) using Amazon's AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have tried the following two methods but both of them still allow the file to be accessed using a URL such as https://bucket-example.s3.amazonaws.com/mwnl.json

(The URL is just an example)

```
$result = $s3Client->putObject(array(
    'ACL'    => 'private',
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => 'mwnl.json',
    'Body'   => $json
));
```

and...

```
$result = $s3Client->putObjectAcl(array(
    'ACL'    => 'private',
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => 'mwnl.json',
    'Body'   => $json
));
```

Comment: Objects should also be private by default. You shouldn't even need to add `'ACL' => 'private'`. How are accessing the objects? If you lookup the object in console, does it say the object is public?

Comment: A URL is provided in the result. I can then use this URL to access the file over HTTPS. Presumably anyone who knows this URL can access the file. I'm not sure what you mean by console.

Comment: Constructing a URL to an object is fairly trivial. It's basically https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{object_key}. Knowing the URL does not mean that you can necessarily access the object. If the object is private, then it requires a signature using AWS access keys from an account that has been granted access.

Comment: If you are creating private objects, but the URLs are granting access to the object (e.g., from a web browser), then something weird is going on and you should probably report it as a bug: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues